# AccessException: Attempted To Read Or Write Protected/Corrupted Memory -- Known Exception, Unknown Reason?

Tags: c++, security, winapi

Yes, I know there's a million threads on this exception, I've probably looked at 20-25 of them, but none of the causes seem to correlate to this, sadly (hence the title, known exception, unknown reason).

I've recently been gaining interest in InfoSec. As my first learners-project, I'd create a basic DLL Injector. Seems to be going well so far, however, this exception is grinding me up, and after some relatively extensive research I'm quite puzzled. Oddly enough, the exception also rises after the function completely finishes.

I couldn't really figure this out myself since external debuggers wouldn't work with my target application, and that was a whole new unrelated issue.

Solutions suggested & attempted so far:

- Fix/Remove thread status checking (it was wrong)
- Ensure the value behind DllPath ptr is being allocated, not the ptr
- Marshaling the C# interop parameters

Anyway, here is my hunk of code:

```cpp
#pragma once

#include "pch.h"
#include "injection.h" // only specifies UserInject as an exportable proto. 

DWORD __stdcall UserInject(DWORD ProcessId, PCSTR DllPath, BOOL UseExtended) {
    DWORD length;
    CHAR* buffer;
    LPVOID memry;
    SIZE_T write;
    HANDLE hProc;
    HMODULE kr32;
    HANDLE thread;

    length = GetFullPathName(
        DllPath,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL
    );
    AssertNonNull(length, INVALID_PATH);

    kr32 = GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll");
    AssertNonNull(kr32, YOUREALLYMESSEDUP);

    buffer = new CHAR[length];

    GetFullPathName(
        DllPath,
        length,
        buffer,
        NULL
    );
    AssertNonNull(buffer, ERR_DEAD_BUFFER);

    hProc = OpenProcess(
        ADMIN,
        FALSE,
        ProcessId
    );
    AssertNonNull(hProc, INVALID_PROCID);

    memry = VirtualAllocEx(
        hProc,
        nullptr,
        sizeof buffer,
        SHELLCODE_ALLOCATION,
        PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE
    );
    AssertNonNull(memry, INVALID_BUFSIZE);

    WriteProcessMemory(
        hProc,
        memry,
        DllPath,
        sizeof DllPath,
        &write
    );
    AssertNonNull(write, ERR_SOLID_BUFFER);

    auto decidePrototype = [](BOOL UseExtended, HMODULE kr32) -> decltype(auto) {
        LPVOID procAddress; 

        if (!UseExtended) {
            procAddress = (LPVOID)GetProcAddress(kr32, LOADLIB_ORD);
        }
        else {
            procAddress = (LPVOID)GetProcAddress(kr32, LOADLIBX_ORD);
        };

        return (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)procAddress;
    };

    auto loadLibraryAddress = decidePrototype(UseExtended, kr32);

    thread = CreateRemoteThread(
        hProc,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        loadLibraryAddress,
        memry,
        NULL,
        NULL
    );
    AssertNonNull(thread, INVALID_ROUTINE);

    WaitForSingleObject(thread, INFINITE);

    // The status stuff is quite weird; it was an attempt at debugging. The error occurs with or without this code.
    // I left it because 50% of the comments below wouldn't make sense. Just be assured this code is positively *not* the problem (sadly). 
    // LPDWORD status = (LPDWORD)1;
    // GetExitCodeThread(thread, status);

    return TRUE // *status;
}
```

One obscure macro would be "ADMIN" which expands to "PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS", shortened to fit in better. Another is "AssertNonNull":

```
#define AssertNonNull(o, p)      if (o == NULL) return p;
```

I've given a shot at debugging this code, but it doesn't halt at any specific point. I've thrown MessageBox tests past each operation (e.g allocation, writing) in addition to the integrity checks and didn't get any interesting responses.

I'm sorry I can't really add much extensive detail, but I'm really stone-walled here, not sure what to do, what information to get, or if there's anything to get. In short, I'm just not sure what to look for.

This is also being called from C#, 1% pseudocode.

```cs
[DllImport(path, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
static extern int UserInject(uint ProcId, string DllPath, bool UseExtended);

uint validProcId;    // integrity tested 
string validDllPath; // integrity tested

UserInject(validProcId, validDllPath, true);
```

If you're interested in my testing application (for reproduction)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

static const std::string toPrint = "Hello, World!\n";

int main() 
{
    while (true) 
    {
        Sleep(1000);

        std::cout << toPrint;
    }
}
```

Comment: I strongly recommend that you change the list of languages — choose one of the three as they are radically different from each other.  You are likely to get downvoted if you keep all three language tags.

Comment: "but it doesn't halt at any specific point." The first step should be to create a reproducible setup for your problem. Write a super-simple program to run your injector on if you have to.

Comment: @Frank Well, I'm kind of doing that. I'm testing against a target application that prints "Hello, World!" every second. The error throws just on the call to the UserInject function after the function finishes (I should add that detail).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks, I shortened it to C++ in specific. Wasn't entirely sure because winapi is C, I'm interoping with C#, and my Injector is in C++.

Comment: @wellinthatcase Sorry, I wrote that comment before you added the second part to your comment. But the general point stand: Timers are not good for reproducibility.

Comment: @Frank I don't understand. How would that invoke the exception, or increase reproduce-ability? The test application is only 3-4 lines of code. A while(true) loop, and a Sleep(1000) call from the Windows header.

Comment: It's not about invoking the exception, I'm specifically targeting the part where you say "but it doesn't halt at any specific point.". If you can set things up so that the crash always happens at the same place, you'll be halfway to understanding what's causing it.

Comment: @Frank Well, that's kind of the issue. The crash doesn't happen in any specific place, just after the function finishes. There's no specific line where functionality halts in the function or test program, so there's no way I can pinpoint "where" the crash happens and add a breakpoint so I know what works and what doesn't. It's a vague issue. All I can figure out is that there's an immediate crash once UserInject finishes. Nothing within, before, or after signals a problem. In essence, the crash does always happen in once place: the finished call, and the reason; I am trying my best to find.

Comment: @Frank I updated the post with my test application's source.

Comment: `DllPath` is a pointer. `sizeof DllPath` evaluates to the size of a pointer. Presumably you meant to calculate the size of the string, in bytes, but aren't.

Comment: Would also be nice to see the actual error diagnostic, unabridged. It's not even clear, which process is faulting. I'm also not entirely convinced, that `string` and `PCSTR` map well, though I neither know .NET nor what magic the P/Invoke marshaller employs. Still a good idea to leave the CLR out of this and implement a client using a programming language with a memory model that's compatible with the callee's.

Comment: Try changing the P/Invoke signature to `int UserInject(uint ProcId, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType::LPStr)]string DllPath, bool UseExtended)` or change the native code to use `PCWSTR` instead of `PCSTR`.

Comment: Whatever you're doing with `GetExitCodeThread` is very wrong. I'm not suprised this crashes.

Comment: True as well. Chances of successfully writing to address 1 are slim.

Comment: @ssbssa That's not it. I've had the same issues before that snippet, and I actually inserted that snippet to try and figure out if there was an issue with the thread before the function ends. But what in specific is wrong with it?

Comment: @IInspectable There was an incompatible implicit conversion between a C# string and a const wchar_t* (LPCWSTR) -- the resulted text was mangled into chinese because of encoding errors, but using a UTF8 Multi-Byte string solved the issue.

Comment: @IInspectable "DllPath is a pointer" I'm gonna check to see if this is the issue right now, I didn't realize this (somehow)

Comment: Alright, well, I tried @Christian.K 's suggestion, additionally dereferenced and also straight up copied the string to ensure it was allocating the actual string, preferred the strlen method over sizeof (included null-term), but I'm still caught.

Comment: It's not Chinese, [it's actually Korean](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20191007-00/?p=102968) (most likely). Regardless, switching to UTF-8 appears to work, *by coincidence*, since UTF-8 and ANSI share the ASCII encoding. Going UTF-16 (which Windows documentation refers to as "Unicode") is the appropriate solution. Though your issue is most likely with `GetExitCodeThread`. It wants you to pass *"a pointer to a variable"*. But you are passing it a pointer with value 1, and there is nothing backing it that lives at address 1.

Comment: @IInspectable I'm sorry, but that's not the problem. With or without the code the error occurs. I inserted that code after the issue to try and debug, removed it for another test, re-inserted, and removed it again; same results. I'm very puzzled. If you have time, you can repro (if you don't believe me).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To my surprise, this wasn't as much an issue with the code as much as it was with the testing application.

The basic injection technique I used is prevented by various exploit protections & security mitigations that Visual Studio 2010+ applies to any applications built in release mode.

If I build my testing application in debug mode, there is no exception. If I use a non-VS built application, there is no exception.

I still need to fix how I create my threads, because no thread is created, but I've figured this out, that should be easy enough.